# Using git log object in ruby

Tags: ruby, git

I'm modifying a ruby gem.

Currently returning a git log object between 2 revision numbers correctly:

```
def log(repo, prev_rev, this_rev)
  repo.log.between(prev_rev, this_rev)
end
```

And storing the commit message using:

```
gitlog_item.each do |commit|
  @message = commit.message
```

My question is what other information is available from this object? Specifically I'm looking for something that can identify the commit uniquely such as an ID, or date & time.

Comment: What does documentation say?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

[This](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/git/1.2.9.1/Git/Object/Commit) should be the documentation you are looking for.

Methods `sha` and `committer_data` seems to do for you.

Comment: Please avoid answering questions by merely providing a link. If that link ever changes, then this answer would be unusable. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the entirety of what your `gitlog_item` contains, you can simply `inspect` it, like so:

```
puts gitlog_item.inspect
```

That'll output the entire object to your console, so you can see everything that's available to you in that object.